# Pass HAML content to HAML partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, render, partial, yield

In Rails/HAML I have the following **partial**:

```
.blur
  .blur.underground= text
  .blur.foreground
    = yield
```

It draws blurred out text in the underground and (should) draw the yielded content in the foreground. Unfortunately, when I call

```
= render 'partial name' do
  %h1 xyz
```

the '%h1 xyz' is not inserted in my partial.

Am I doing something wrong or is there an alternative way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me

```
= render layout: 'partial name' do
  %h1 xyz
```

(note the 'layout') and then

```
.blur
  .blur.underground= text
  .blur.foreground
    = yield
```

produced

```
div class="blur">
  <div class="blur underground">text</div>
  <div class="blur foreground">
    <h1>xyz</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works beautifully! Note: if you also want to pass local variables, you need the locals symbol: = render layout: 'partial name', locals: {text: 'xyz'}